# case class with logic what is the idiomatic way

Tags: scala, functional-programming

What is the FP idiomatic way for this: let's say I have this

```
trait Name

object Name{
 def apply(name: String): Name = {
     if (name.trim.isEmpty || name.trim.length < 3)
       InvalidName
     else 
       ValidName(name.trim)
    }
 }

case object InvalidName extends Name
case class ValidName(name:String) extends AnyVal with Name
```

Now I have some helper functions such as

```
def split = name.splitAt(" ")
//some more functions
```

which way is more idiomatic:

1. Put them in the case class it self but that some how makes the case class to contain some logic however I can do something like :

   `val n = ValidName("john smith")`

   `val (first, last) = n.split`
2. Put them in dedicated object but then the method will look like

   `def split(n: ValidName) = n.name.splitAt(" ")`
3. Create an object with implicit class that will accept Name and will call the methods

What do you think ?

Comment: Note that using `Name(...)` inside the object's `apply` method will call `Name.apply(...)` (call itself) and overflow the stack (i think, haven't tested it)... you should probably replace it with `new Name(...)` to ensure it calls the class constructor directly

Comment: @AlvaroCarrasco good point, I over simplified the example. I edited the question to avoid situation as you said

Answer (score 2):

There is no major issue with adding logic to a `case class`, especially when it is just extracting the data in a different format. (It becomes problematic when you add data members to a `case class`).

So I would do option 1 and not worry about it!

---

In response to the comments, `case class` is actually just a shortcut for creating a class with a whole bunch of useful pre-implemented methods. In particular, the `unapply` method allows a `case class` to be used in pattern matching, and `equals` does an element-wise comparison of the fields of two instances.

And there are a bunch of other methods to extract the data from the `case class` in different ways. The most obvious are `toString` and `copy`, but there are others like `hashCode` and all the stuff inherited from `Product`, such as `productIterator`.

Since a `case class` already has methods to extract the data in useful ways, I see no objection to adding your `split` method as another way of extracting data from the `case class`.

Comment: Case classes are not suppose to hold the function for the data they are used to define Algebraic structure and mostly used for pattern matching.

Comment: actually these whole bunch of pre-implemented methods are inherited by trait product it doesn’t have these. And that’s what I said function on data should remain outside in some other entity like trait or object etc.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I am somehow between your suggestion to the my  opinion that aligns with what @RamanMishra said regarding case class as algebraic data type. I usually want tend to leave biz logic outside the case class . I can of course create an object that will contain this logic as option 3 but it seems to be redundant overhead wdyt ?

Comment: @igx I agree that business logic should not be inside a `case class`, but I think simple operations are OK as long as they relate directly to the values in the class itself. It is OK for an ADT to have other methods that unpick them, as well as pattern matching.

Answer (score 2):

More idiomatic:

```
case class Name private (name: String) {
  lazy val first :: last :: Nil = name.split(" ").toList
}
object Name {
  def fromString (name: String): Either[String, Name] = {
    if (name.trim.isEmpty || name.trim.length < 3) Left("Invalid name")
    else Right(new Name(name.trim))
  }
}
```

Or maybe this:

```
case class Name (first: String, last: String) {
  lazy val fullName = s"$first $last"
}
object Name {
  def fromString (name: String): Either[String, Name] = {
    if (name.trim.isEmpty || name.trim.length < 3) Left("Invalid name")
    else {
      val first :: last :: Nil = name.split(" ").toList
      Right(new Name(first, last))
    }
  }
}
```

In scala it's more idiomatic to represent failure cases through the use of `Either` than through inheritance. If you have an instance of `N`, you can't call any functions on it, you'll probably have to pattern match it. But a type like `Either` already comes with functions like `map`, `fold`, etc. that makes it easier to work with.

Having a private constructor helps ensure that you can only create a valid `Name` because the only way to create one is through the `fromString` method.

DO NOT use implicits for this. There's no need and would only make for confusing code. Not really what implicits are for.

Comment: I see but the pattern matching is a specific solution . the thing here is that we apply some biz logic on one of the members of the class

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on context.  In this case, if most of the methods you are using are just slight tweaks to `String` methods, you might want to consider a fourth option:

```
case class Name(name: String)
implicit def NameToString(n: Name) = n.name

Name("Iron Man").split(" ") // Array(Iron, Man)
```

Comment: I do see the benefit of your suggestion but as for the design decision :
You do not want to fill your code with implicits. you want to use implicits (IMHO) where you want to extend an external lib to fit your dsl or convenient . or for necessary conversion. in your example you simply convert `Name` to `String` which is somehow even dangerous for example you can make operation such as 
```
val name = Name("John Doe")
name + " something"
```
this is unexpected behaviour